# Why does dreamweaver show CSS background color in design view but not live view?

Tags: html, css, cordova, phonegap-build, dreamweaver

I am building a mobile application and in my CSS I have it designated to have the background color changed to a blue. I can see the changes in my design view, but not in the live view. I am using Dreamweaver and PhoneGap, and as such when I build my project on Phone Gap the live view is what is maintained, and the absence of the background color is kept.. I don't know what is going on, any help would be huge!

//html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Travelers Aid</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style-one.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

//home page//
<div data-role="page" id="Home">
<h1 id="title" align="center">Travelers Aid</h1>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu">
        <option value="english">English</option>
        <option value="french">French</option>
        <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
  </select>
  <div data-role="content"><a href="#SearchPage" data-role="button">Travel</a>

</body>
</html>
```

//css

```
@charset "utf-8";
#Home{background-color: rgb(26,71,81);}
h1{color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
   font-family: raleway;}
```

The weird thing is that the text color is maintained... so I really don't understand.

Comment: you have a few html errors, check the code and fix it https://validator.w3.org/   your h1 'center' is old deprecated code, use 'h1 { text-align: center; }'

Comment: thank you for the heads up!

Comment: This is probably best asked in a dreamweaver forum.